# Simulate Laravel Request class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, http

i have a registration method in Laravel receive object from HTTP request,
how i can receive HTTP request data in Codeigniter?

```
public static function adduser(Request $request)
{ // my laravel function
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user-name   = $request->name;
/*
save data to DB
...
...
*/


}
```

Comment: See [Accessing Form Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#accessing-form-data)

Comment: i'm not using form, i have an android app, and i want to send data from the app to Codeigniter..

Comment: @hasko that is all the same if you use HTTP

Comment: in laravel i receive the object as a parameter for the method,
but in Codeigniter, i must know the input name

Answer (score 0):

you can create a controller and set `$this->input->post('Name');` you will get the data.

Comment: it did not work with me, 
also i don't know the name of the input which i will receive.